# DV is customer bank choice

Tags: multinomial-logit

DV is Customer bank choice that is categorical with 5 response variable, like CBE,AIB,COOP,OIB,AB banks customers selected as sample thus i need to use multinomial regression, but i am not clear with how to code them

Comment: What software are you using?